# Create a button dynamically within the same layout by clicking on an existing button in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to add a new button to the view by clicking on an existing static button within the same view. And the button should stay there in the view until we manually delete it.

Browsing for help on this for a while and all I can get to is creating dynamic buttons. Hope any of you can help me out in what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: create button dynamically and set layoutparams also programatically as per your need

Answer (score 1):

On your existing button click listener call this function.

```
private void addButton(){ 
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);//create a layout in you content view  
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 

    Button newButton = new Button(this);
    newButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    newButton.setText("Button Text");
    newButton.setId(1);//some id
    layout.addView(row); // add button in layout
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must access to layout with findView and add your button to that like this code which located in onCreate function in your activity :

```
Button staticBtn = (Button)(findViewById(R.id.staticBtnID));
LayoutParam staticBtnLayoutParam = staticBtn.getLayoutParam();
Button btn = new Button(this);
int width = 0; //you can use staticBtnLayoutParam.getWidth(); or .getX(); to get staticBtn parameters and set your param related to that
int height = 0 ;  
btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width , height));
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)(findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutID)); 
layout.addView(button);
```

Best Regards